# Revert modprobe -r wlan0

Tags: 14.04, wireless, modprobe

I followed some instructions hoping it will help me extend my battery life, as my Wi-Fi card takes a comparatively large amount of power. In doing so, I was told to execute "modprobe -r wlan0" without knowing what exactly it does. Suddenly, I lose my connection to the campus Wi-Fi and cannot connect back. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to reboot your computer. The change you made is just temporary.

In order to fix the situation without rebooting the computer, you have to find the name of the module that drives your WiFi card and that you just unloaded. The `lshw` should help you. For example, on my laptop this is the stanza related to the WiFi card:

> ```
>       *-network DISABLED
>            description: Wireless interface
>            product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
>            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
>            physical id: 0
>            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>            logical name: wlan0
>            version: 01
>            serial: 00:08:ca:f7:af:26
>            width: 64 bits
>            clock: 33MHz
>            capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
>            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16-2-amd64 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
>            resources: irq:17 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
> ```

The `driver=ath9k` piece on the next-to-last line tells me that the driver module is `ath9k`. Thus I would have to issue the command

> ```
> modprobe ath9k
> ```

And then wait for the network management service to detect it again and re-establish the connection.